# How to get the unique values and transmute the values from a different column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I generated a unique value based from a column but what I want to get as a result is the transmuted value from a different column. Here's the code for your reference:

```
x = [[123, "M"],
     [321, "F"],
     [456, "M"],
     [678, "F"],
     [654, "M"],
     [123, "M"],
     [678, "F"],
     [678, "F"],
    ]

x = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ["ID", "GENDER"])
```

Getting the unique value

```
[in]: x["ID"].unique()
[out]: array([123, 321, 456, 678, 654], dtype=int64)
```

Expected Result:

```
[out]: ["M", "F", "M", "F", "M"]
```

Comment: `x.drop_duplicates('ID')['GENDER']` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ID is unique, so the gender also the same if the ID is identical. That means you have duplicates. So you can use:

```
x.drop_duplicates()
```